# C++: confused by type on computing distances between iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator

I need to rotate elements in a `std::vector` so that it holds at the beginning the first duplicate element. To be clearer, say if I have:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 3 7 8
```

Then I want:

```
3 4 5 6 3 7 8 1 2
```

Ok, lets use `std::rotate()`, and build a function to get the first duplicate position:

```
int main() {
   std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,3,7,8 };
   auto it = FindFirstDuplicate(v);
   cout << "first dupe is " << *it << " at " << it - v.begin() << endl;
   std::rotate( v.begin(), it, v.end() );
}
```

The idea for that task is to store one by one the elements in a new vector, until I find that the one I am about to add is already in this new vector.

But I stumble on iterators issues, so it doesn't compile. I get confused with the type of the different iterators, and on const/non const iterator issues.

Here is my code at present, [try it online here](http://ideone.com/IwAHgu) (skipped `std::` for readability):

```
template<typename T>
typename vector<T>::iterator FindFirstDuplicate( const vector<T>& v )
{
   vector<T> nv; // new temp vector
   nv.reserve( v.size() );
   for( auto it1 = v.cbegin(); it1 != v.cend(); it1++ )
   {
      auto it2 = find( nv.begin(), nv.end(), *it1 ); // search elem in new vector
      if( it2 == nv.end() )                          // if not present,
         nv.push_back( *it1 );                       //   add in new vector
      else                                           // else, we found a dupe
         return v.begin() + (it2-nv.begin());
   }
   return v.begin();
}
```

To save your eyes, I don't post the error message, but to me it seems that the compiler complains about the different types of the iterators on the last line. I also tried by using non const iterator for `it1`, but I still get that problem.

Any help appreciated, on this iterator issue, but also any advice on the algorithm by itself.

Comment: You don't need the temporary vector in `findFirstDuplicate`.  Just something like `while ( current != end && std::find( std::next( current ), end, *current ) != end ) { ++ current; }` is sufficient (with `current` and `end` initialized with `v.begin()` and `v.end()`).

Comment: ok, thanks. But if I prefer to keep it only for readability purpose, won't the compiler be able to optimize it ? I personaly like the idea of not trying to over-optimize code myself and let that to the compiler.

Comment: I find the version without the extra variable clearer: it makes it very clear that you're looking for duplicates in the same vector (and not somewhere else) and it avoids complicated iterator arithmetic to determine the return value.

Comment: @James Kanze ok, I see, I'll try that. I'm just not familiar with `std::next()`, so it wasn't very clear for me at first sight. But I like learning new tricks, thanks!

Comment: @James Kanze I posted a full version of what you suggested, with a minor correction, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return an `iterator` from a `const` reference to `vector`. You can see the problem in this minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator foo(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    return v.begin(); // const overload returns const_iterator
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(42);
    foo(v); // Instantiate function template: ERROR
}
```

What you can do is pass a non-const reference to your finder function:

```
template<typename T>
typename vector<T>::iterator FindFirstDuplicate( vector<T>& v )
{
   ...
```

Comment: Wow, was so simple... I got fooled by the (as usual) overly verbose error message, and didn't even think about checking the arguments constness. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, and as suggested by @James Kanze (credit goes to him), here is a shorter, corrected and completed version. This one also returns the position of the duplicate found.

```
template<typename T>
typename vector<T>::iterator
FindFirstDuplicate( vector<T>& v, typename vector<T>::iterator& dupe )
{
   auto current = v.begin();
   while (
      current != v.end() &&
      (dupe = std::find( std::next( current ), v.end(), *current )) == v.end()
   )
   {
       ++current;
   }
   return current;
}

// test case
int main()
{   
   vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3 };
   auto dupe = v.begin();
   auto it = FindFirstDuplicate(v,dupe);
   cout << "first dupe is " << *it << " at pos " << it - v.cbegin() << endl;
   cout << "dupe is " << *dupe << " at pos " << dupe - v.cbegin() << endl;
}
```

It is available [here](http://ideone.com/Flm6gk) for experimenting. To be complete, the version I use returns actually a `std::pair` of both iterators.